# How to POST Data using retrofit2 when i selected form-data in POSTMAN

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

When i used to post data through a Api using retrofit i am getting response 400 when i used @FormUrlEncoded in my interface but in postman i used form-data to post can u please help me

Here is my Interface

```
public interface SignupApiService {

@POST("users")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<ResponseBody> savePost(@Field("email") String email,
                            @Field("password") String password,
                            @Field("role") int role);
}
```

Here is my Signup Activity

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = SignupClient
                        .getInstance().getApi()
                        .savePost(email, password, roleValue);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        int statusCode = response.code();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Log.d("SignupActivity", "onResponse" +statusCode);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

Here is my Java Class

```
public class SignupClient {

private static SignupClient mInstance;
private static Retrofit retrofit;
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://74.207.233.160/api/v1/";

private SignupClient(){

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

public static synchronized SignupClient getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null){
        mInstance = new SignupClient();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public SignupApiService getApi() {
    return retrofit.create(SignupApiService.class);
}
}
```

Here when i use formurlencoded i am getting response 400.
how to use form data here insted of formurlencoded.
Or any changes is required in my postman

Postman When it is success here i have selected form-data
[image: Postman One]

postman when i selected form-url-encoded
[image: Postman two]

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript??

Comment: there might be some error on your backhand ?

Comment: just remove FormDataUrl annotation, it will still work. form-data in Postman is for sending data as Multipart form data and i think it's not as @FormUrlEncoded. can you post your backend API code.

Comment: Have you tried with setting content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in postman?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your interface method like this

```
@POST("users")
Call<ResponseBody> savePost(@PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> map);
```

and where you call this method

```
Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("user[email]", RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM,email))
# same way add password and other params
and call the interface method by passing this map
```

Comment: @PartMap parameters can only be used with multipart encoding. This error i am getting

Comment: If I use @Multipart  in interface i am getting response 500

Comment: can you add the updated code it will be more helpful @Yas